# Merging many dataframes based on row ID in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am attempting to merge many (~40) dataframes (i.e. pH, fieldpH, AlkT, …) into one dataframe based on a unique identifier (row ID) “SampleID”, however, when I attempt to merge these files using the script below the file reaches 75MB and crashes. The final, combined file will be large, but 75MB seems a little extreme.

I’m not sure if I am compounding the files and accidentally making the file size larger?

Any help or insight as to how to fix this problem or a suggestion of a better way to merge numerous dataframes based on row ID would be greatly appreciated!

**Disclaimer:** that I am definitely a beginner with R and coding in general.

```
## Subset original file ##
pH<-subset(data, VARIABLE_TRIM == "PH")
pH<-pH[c("SampleID", "MONTH", "YEAR", "FLAG", "VALUE_CONV")]
names(pH)[5]<-"pH"
fieldpH<-subset(data, VARIABLE_TRIM == "FIELD PH")
fieldpH<-fieldpH[c("SampleID", "FLAG", "VALUE_CONV")]
names(fieldpH)[3]<-"Field pH"

## Merge dataframes ##
fulldata <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "SampleID",
                                        all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE),
                   list(pH, fieldpH, AlkT, Hard, Hard2, DO, DOC, TOC, Spec, 
                        SpecField, TempField, Temp, SbT, SbD, AsT, AsD, CdT,
                        CdD, CrT))
```

Comment: definitely check out the join_all() functoin from the plyr package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: This duplicate gives you many different options for joining/merging dataframes

Comment: @divibisan I don't think this is a duplicate, related post is this one [merge list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303). And the issue is their implementation is not giving expected output.

Comment: Maybe. From the question as it's stated, there doesn't seem to be anything particularly unusual here, they're just having problems getting `merge` to work, in which case, barring any clarifying edits, directing them to the canonical question on joining data frames is the best thing we can do. Your duplicate is definitely a better choice, though

Comment: This may be a problem of going from long to wide format.  In which case other options other than merge are better.  If we could get a sample of the data for 1 or 2 sample ids make understanding the problem easier.

Comment: The plyr package worked fantastically! Thank you all! Apologies for the delay, I'm still not sure how to indicate that one of the comments provided the solution.